# Postgresql php function to use value from one query in another

Tags: php, postgresql, function

I need to get one select value $code into another in a function, but keep breaking everything. This is the function.

```
function agent_specific()
{
    $dbh = dbh_get();
    $code = '';
    $options = '';

    $sql = 'select code from staff where user = 14';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    return $code;

    $sql = 'select code, name from outlet
        where code = ' . $code . '';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while (true) {
        $r = $stmt->fetch();
        if (is_bool($r)) break;
        $options .= '<option value="' . $r['code'] . '">' . $r['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    dbh_free($dbh);
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: `return $code;` looks fishy to me. do `$code="$r[code]";` instead.

Comment: @Jasen didn't work

Comment: I can't guess why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your code  .. you should not use the return in the middle of the function  .. because return end the excution of the function and "return"  the value  to a function caller ..the code after return will never executed

Anyway in your case you could also avoid the use of two query just using

```
select staff.code, outlet.name 
from staff  
INNER JOIN outlet  ON  (staff.code = outlet.code  
    and staff.user = 14 )
```

Comment: doesn't work, can't figure out how it would work either, but inner join seems like the way I should be looking at it

Comment: What mean  "doesn't work"  .. you have error  ?? show the exact error message ..  wrong result ?  add  a proper data sample the expected  result and you actual result  ...

Comment: I worked it out using your code and a bit of research. Will come in very useful.